# Apache/Rails/Passenger Displaying Site Index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, apache2, passenger

I have a Rails app that I have successfully tested with Mongrel and Webkit.  Now I want to test deployment.  I set up a VMWare Image using Ubuntu 8.04.  I have installed Rails following this method https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails with the exception of using Gems 1.3 instead of 1.2.  I have configured and installed Passenger.  However, when I visit my sites index (http://some.ip.that.i'm.testing/) I simply get the directory index of my rails site.  I should note that since I'm testing I just dumped my app in /var/www.

My Apache2 error.log file shows this and this only:

> [Tue Sep 30 15:10:41 2008] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/2.0.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

Any idea what could be causing this problem?  It seems Passenger is configured properly, but I'm not sure why my rails app is not displaying and why the site's directory listing is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two questions:

1) Is Rails running at all on the server? Passenger should start Rails automatically on first request - if you do a ps, do you see it running?

2) Which directory are you seeing - is it your rails directory or the public/ directory? If it's the former, your symlink is likely pointing the wrong place (it should go to public/).

(I've seen this problem before and am trying to remember how I debugged it... these are my first two thoughts.)

Comment: It's because it wasn't pointed to public.  Thanks for your help.