# Passenger showing index of folder, rather than rendering site with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, apache2, passenger

Similar to this question: [Apache/Rails/Passenger Displaying Site Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154959/apache-rails-passenger-displaying-site-index)

Only difference is that my app is pointing to the public directory.

Running `ps aux | grep rails` shows that there is a rails instance running, but it's not rendering my app

Here is my apache2.conf: http://pastebin.com/twipcruz

One possible problem is that PassengerRoot and PassengerRuby are pointing to different versions, but this block was simply copied and pasted from the `passenger-install-apache2-module` output

```
#Passenger Setup
LoadModule passenger_module /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/passenger-3.0.11
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

getting this from the log:

```
10:13:24 2012] [error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: The Passenger spawn server script, '/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server', does not exist. Please check whether the 'PassengerRoot' option is specified correctly.
```

Comment: PassengerRuby being ruby 1.8 but PassengerRoot pointing at a version of the gem compiled for 1.9 is a bad thing

Comment: That was just copied and pasted from the installer. What can I do to change it?

Comment: The installer normally gets it right (the install apache module script takes a --snippet option that regenerates those lines). PassengerRuby should be the path to the ruby interpreter that matches the passenger root directive.

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install passenger with rvmsudo, you have just run the passenger install.